# Any service to convert an API string response into a json response?

Tags: json, string, api, zapier

I'm trying to use an API to verify email addresses for my newsletter, but the API only returns a string.

I am trying to use it with Zapier, but Zapier requires the API to return json if it is to do anything useful with the response.

Any idea if there's a way of working around this? For example, is there a service that will basically wrap the resulting string in json so Zapier can use the result?

Like a service that you could ping, which will then ping the API endpoint of the email verification service, and will convert the result to json before returning it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here from the Zapier platform team.

I'm not sure how you're calling the external service. It sounds like you're using a webhook step, which is probably why the response is getting eaten (we expect json or XML, though simple text support isn't a bad idea - I'll make a note).

The easiest solution here is probably to run a small code step instead. You can make the same request and are in control of the result. We use the `fetch` library, so it should be straightforward. Something to the affect of:

```
fetch('https://emailservice.com?email=' + inputData.email)
 .then(function(response) {
   return response.text()  // returns a promise
 })
 .then(function(text) {
   callback(null, {result: text})
 })
 .catch(callback)
```

Then you should be able to use the API response like normal!

Comment: Thanks David, that's really helpful! I'll give it a go :)